# Overriding HTML template of library component in angular 7

Tags: angular, templates, overriding

I've created an angular library project which is used to render simple component login form design is horizontal bootstrap form.

I'm using this library in my another angular project which is working fine.

but, I want to change the layout of the library component HTML, and I don't want to change directly in the library project.

In angular, we can override function through super() call in the constructor but **how to override HTML template?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new class that derives from your library component and declare a new `@Component` decorator, any new Component metadata will overwrite any previous metadata.

```js
import { LibraryComponent } from 'library';

@Component {
  templateUrl: 'my-new-template.html'
}
export class MyNewComponent extends LibraryComponent {
  //
}
```

Source: https://medium.com/@gerard.sans/angular-2-new-features-in-angular-2-3-f2e73f16a09e